# How to get "position:fixed" css to work in IE 7+ with TRANSITIONAL doctype?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, doctype

I know that `position:fixed;` was not supported by IE until IE 7, and it only works in IE 7 if you have a `STRICT DOCTYPE`.

My question is: "How do I get it work with IE 7 with `TRANSITIONAL DOCTYPE`?"

Please don't suggest changing a `DOCTYPE`, as this does not answer my question, thank you.

Comment: Less time to spend with family - thanks to IE.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need a Strict DOCTYPE for `fixed` support. You only need a DOCTYPE that triggers [Standards Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types) (or ‘almost standards’). That can be a transitional doctype such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

as long as the system ID (the URI at the end) is included.

If your pages really *are* relying on Quirks Mode (ugh!), I'm sorry but you cannot use `fixed` and will have to resort to JavaScript hacks (but then you might need those for IE6 anyway).

Comment: Does html5 trigger 'almost standards' mode? `<!doctype html>`

Comment: @Jonny: The HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` triggers full Standards Mode.

Answer (score 10):

Fixed position does not work for me even with the Transitional/Strict Doc types. However I am using IE9 in compatibility mode and that is suppose to render using the IE8 runtime libraries. To fix this issue I had to add the following CSS to element.

```
.elementToBeFixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

It does not work with Top or Left being missing you have to explicitly set them to zero (or your desired value) for it to work in all versions of IE....Needless to say IE sucks.

Comment: Just FYI: Even in IE9, compatibility mode uses IE7 rendering engine in *quirks mode*. It doesn't render anything like IE8.

Comment: @Chris, I realized that recently, it even sends out the IE7 user agent...Thanks