# IE7 strange behaviour with fixed header and 960.gs

Tags: css, css-position

Hi all… can you give me your opinion on the following link? http://dante.edoardobiasini.it
For some reason in ie7, the above fixed header is not centered but goes all the way to the right…
Thank you

Comment: A similar question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628265/how-to-get-positionfixed-css-to-work-in-ie-7-with-transitional-doctype

Comment: I've answered your question, but please read this: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) In short, you should include some relevant code in your question, and try to make a test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 does not always behave properly with `left: auto`, which is what `#branding` has at the moment.

To fix it, add this:

```css
#branding {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px; /* 960/2 */
}
```

Comment: Also, you should change the doctype back to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. It's a better choice than the one you have right now.