# Floating Link in Page

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css-float

I want to make floating link which will be displayed in webpage whether user scrolls up/down the page.

```
<div id="valids" style="position: fixed; bottom: 5px; left: 5px;">
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" class="valid">
<img alt="Valid XHTML 1.0" src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10-blue" style="border: 0pt none ; width: 88px; height: 31px;"/></a>
<a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://www.reapercharlie.com" class="valid">
<img alt="Valid CSS 2.1" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss-blue" style="border: 0pt none ; width: 88px; height: 31px;"/></a>
</div>
```

This is perfectly displayed in Firefox, Chrome, IE 9 onwards.
But I need to make it work with IE 8 and IE 7 atleast.

In IE 8 and IE 7, the content goes up along with page content.

Comment: added code. had some issue while pasting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post [How to get "position:fixed" css to work in IE 7+ with TRANSITIONAL doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628265/how-to-get-positionfixed-css-to-work-in-ie-7-with-transitional-doctype) suggests that you need to add a doctype to get IE7/8 to trigger standards mode, have you tried this?

if you don't want to mess around with doctypes, you could always try using jQuery instead http://jsfiddle.net/wRSZ2/.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#mybox").css("top", scrollTop + "px");
});​
```

The the code above, you could simply hook up to the window scroll event and scroll the box manually along with the window. Looks pretty ok to me, but I haven't tested it on IE 7/8!

Hope it helps!

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark as answered! (green tick) :)