# Floating DIV in quirks mode

Tags: javascript, css-position, quirks-mode

Im working with a very badly coded CMS which only works in Quirks Mode and I want to place a floating div at the right bottom of the page. I've spent the last 2 hours searching for a possible way to do this. Normally I would just: Position:fixed; but this won't work in Quirks Mode.

Is it possible to do with javascript?
If, then how?

Comment: You've already tried position:absolute I assume? And when you say page, do you mean the actual HTML page or the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the DOCTYPE? [How to get "position:fixed" css to work in IE 7+ with TRANSITIONAL doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628265/how-to-get-positionfixed-css-to-work-in-ie-7-with-transitional-doctype)

And using HTML5 doctype?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Have you tried an absolute position instead? Having the div as a child of the body tag.

Comment: I can't change the doctype because it will break the CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Quirks mode in IE 7 can also be triggered when coding HTML 4.01 documents. Inserting a comment before the DTD will trigger this backwards compatible mode in both IE 6 and IE 7.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and It isn't always obvious which rendering mode a browser is in. In IE address line, type in

```
javascript:alert(document.compatMode)
```

Thanks,
Brendon

Comment: I tried pressing F12 in Internet Explorer and it said Quirks.

Comment: please add those 2 doc types on your html page.... most probably quirk mode will be resolve. and check there by pressing of F12

Comment: But the problem isn't that it's quirks mode. As I mentioned above, then it's badly coded and only works in quirks mode. If I change to one of the doctypes, it will misbehave and the menus will lose color. I need a way to have a floating div IN quirks mode.... And I use: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">