# Using jQuery to set position from absolute to fixed in IE7 & IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, position

```
var uf = $('.utilsFloat');
var topValue = $('.article .header').offset().top;
uf.css({
    top : topValue,
    marginLeft : -137,
    position: 'absolute'
});

$(document).scroll(function() {

    var fixedShareTools = $(document).scrollTop() >= topValue;

    if (fixedShareTools) {
        uf.css(
            {
                top : 10 + "px",
                "position" : "fixed"
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        uf.css(
            {
                "position" : "absolute",
                top : topValue + "px"
            }
        )
    }});
```

The code above is trying to set an item's position attribute to "fixed" when you scroll past a header on the page. It works great in everything except IE8 and 7. Are there issues with the jQuery .css() method in IE7/8?

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: IE has in general always had problems with fixed/absolute. For a long while fixed wasn't even supported in the spec. I don't see why switching would be problematic ie IE 8, but 7 or below I could see an issue potentially. On the flip side of that maybe the logic is a bit upside down. Absolute and fixed both work off the screens view port for initial placement (or at least I think this is the case) of course if you put it in a relative position element thats a different case, but in all without that 0 position starts at the top of the window and not necessarily the content.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628265/how-to-get-positionfixed-css-to-work-in-ie-7-with-transitional-doctype

Comment: I've viewed nearly every thread on this topic already and have tried the aforementioned solutions. Setting the position to fixed, and top/left to 0 causes the element to disappear from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.. I ended up using classes instead and this worked.

```
if ($('body').hasClass('content-article')) {
//Pulling the top position value of the article header so the share tools align with it always
var uf = $('.utilsFloat');
var topValue = $('.article .header').offset().top;
uf.css({top : topValue });

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var fixedShareTools = $(window).scrollTop() >= topValue;

    if (fixedShareTools) {
        uf.removeClass('absolute');
        uf.addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        uf.removeClass('fixed');
        uf.addClass('absolute');
        uf.css(top, topValue + "px");
    }});}
```