# Fixed position in Internet explorer 7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, position, internet-explorer-7

In internet Explorer 7 .. The CSS property "position: Fixed" doesn't work.

I searched for a solution and found that to solve this I have to specify the DOC type in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I'm using jquery and I can't specify the DOC type. 
Is there any work around solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why using of jquery does not allow you to specify DOCTYPE ?

Comment: I read that it is a read-only property in jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628265/how-to-get-positionfixed-css-to-work-in-ie-7-with-transitional-doctype

Comment: this might help u... http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html

Answer (score 1):

DOCTYPE has nothing with jquery. DOCTYPE is a way to tell browsers how to treat your page (which standards to use), Specifying DOCTYPE will change your page to Strict rendering mode (in contrast of Quirks mode). Read here for more details: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Solution for you: just specify DOCTYPE line at the very beginning of your HTML/ASPX page. This is the way how it is used. Than jquery will show it for you in its read-only property.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a DOCTYPE to the current document(or modify it).

From the [MDN-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.doctype):
*doctype is a **read-only property**.*

Comment: This is not correct, you can specify DOCTYPE directly on your page. You just cannot change it after that dynamically (using plain javascript or jquery or anything else)

Comment: “You cannot add a DOCTYPE to the current document(or modify it).” In JavaScript, correct. But if you can edit the HTML of the page, then you can change the doctype.